# Phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect for Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, phonegap-plugins

Is there any phonegap-plugin for facebook-connect for Blackberry or any other way in which facebook share can be done in blackberry using Phonegap?

Answer (score 0):

you need to get a native facebook jar for blackberry, which was available on developer.facebook After getting an app id you'll process that in to your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Currently no Fb plugin available bor blkbery check available plugins [link](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/BlackBerry).
**But you can implement** fb share using inAppBrowser just open facebook share url on childBrowser (InappBrowser)  and you can able to share on facebook .
Eg : `http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=URL or anything` try to open this url on Child browser , then user can login and make share .